# BitmapFactory causing app to crash on orientation change

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm writing an app that stores a String in an SQLite database, which represents the filepath of an image on the /sdcard/. I have this code in the `onCreate()` one of my activities:

```
final Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

String imageStr = receivedIntent.getExtras().getString("picture");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pPicture);
File file = new File (imageStr);
if (file.exists()) {
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageStr);
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The code works when I'm first loading the activity, but when I switch between screen orientations, it crashes my application. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? I'd like to bee able to continue switching between orientations, but I don't need to refresh each time.

Also, I'm somewhat new, so please try to keep your answers not too complicated if possible.

Note that the file does exist in all cases.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your app crashes because of `OutOfMemoryException`. Try recylcing the bitmap in `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pPicture);
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I'm having the same issue in a ListView, where each item has an icon. Where should I implement this code for that situation? In the ArrayAdapter class or the ListView class?

Comment: You're welcome! It will be nice if you accept the answer. Maybe it will help someone else. As for your second question, it's better to add it as another question then to discuss it in comments.

Comment: Or for checking the class instance => if (BitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(drawable)) {